# Regex Help Simple Pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I am very weak with Regex and need help. Input looks like the following:

```
<span> 10/28 &nbsp;&nbsp;Currency:&nbsp;USD
```

Desired output is `10/28`.

I need to get all text between the `<span>` and "Currency:" that are numbers, a "/" character, or a ":" character. No spaces.

Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example input and output you want?

Comment: Sample input: <span> 12/02 Currency:
Desired output: 12/02

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**: What you're describing is three parts.

What we *do* want is one or more characters that are digits, forward slash, and `:`: `[0-9/:]*` (the asterisk means "zero or more instances"). Surrounded by:

- `<span>(optional stuff we don't want)` is represented as: `<span>[^0-9/:]*`
- `(optional stuff we don't want)Currency` is:  `[^0-9/:]*Currency`

(The `^` means "not") - so this will essentially match any number of characters which is not the bits we want, including things like `&nbsp;`

In c#:

```
string pattern = @"<span>[^0-9/:]*(?<value>[0-9/:]*)[^0-9/:]*Currency";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.SingleLine | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string output = match.Groups["value"].Value;
```

Comment: @Bob sorry, I misread part of your question. I edited to fix it.

Comment: Still not working, here's an actually sample of the text:

<span> 10/28      &nbsp;&nbsp;Currency:&nbsp;USD

Comment: @Jeremy correcting errors is always appreciated, but don't get too edit-happy just removing correct but superfluous text.

Comment: @Bob you didn't mention you had non-breaking space entities in there! You just said space :D

Comment: Yeah, I thought `[\s]` over `\s` was setting a bad example, but that was a bit pedantic.  Sorry.  Also, I was wrong about the colon after Currency not being part of the input.  So, wrong on two counts.  I'll stop now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good place to start. Using others code is fine at first, but if you don't learn this stuff you're going to be eternally doomed to asking questions every time you need a new regex.

[Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)

[Regular Expressions Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520689)

[Online tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html)

spend some time, learn the basics, and pretty soon you'll be helping us with our regex problems.

Comment: I'm in a major crunch, if I had the time to learn it now I wouldn't be asking questions.

Comment: that's cool, read this answer again when you have some free time :P

Comment: -1 Sorry, but saying "learn regular expressions" isn't answering his specific question.

Comment: Reading the first book at the moment, and it's great!

Comment: @CAbbott no problem, you aren't wrong about that by any means.  I still think it needs to be addressed regardless.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Andomar yeah, I feel alot more comfortable with regular expressions after reading that book.

Comment: Thanks for plugging Regular Expressions Cookbook. If anyone doesn't have a copy yet, O'Reilly and I are doing a giveaway at http://www.regexguru.com in which anyone can participate until the end of the month (28 Feb 2010).

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
<span>(?>.*?([\d/:]+)).*?Currency
```

The `.*?` matches the least amount of anything (non-greedy regex.)  It should work for your example `<span> 10/28 &nbsp;&nbsp;Currency:&nbsp;USD`.

This is [a nice site](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) to test regular expressions.

Comment: This regex will suffer from catastrophic backtracking when `<span>` is not followed by `Currency`.

Comment: @Jeremy Stein: Tested and New York City wasn't flooded.  What do you mean by catastrophic?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html  In this case, I guess it's only a problem if there are a lot of digits in the subject.  Try it on the source of this page, or on `<span>5555...` where there are about 100 5s.  Anyhow, there's an easy fix, which I'll make for you now.

Comment: Hmm.. That must be chapter 5.